# KDE, how to have "tail -f" constantly on a dedicated panel?

Tags: kde, panel, log, plasma, tail

Plasma has this nice plasmoid called [File Watcher](http://techbase.kde.org/Projects/Plasma/Plasmoids#File_Watcher).
At work I have 2 monitors. I would like to put this plasmoid on an empty panel on the second monitor. So that

```
tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log
```

would be always visibile on the panel, but unfortunately I'm not able to make the plasmoid go on the 100% of the panel's with.

Is there a way for doing this?
Workarounds and/or alternatives are welcome

Answer (score 0):

You can use `KSystemLog`, placing the window wherever you want.